# Add functions to super class that will be used by the subclass also

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to JS and it seems everything seems to have so many ways to do that will make you confused.Anyways this is what I am trying to do:

```js
//SuperClass
function Animal(name, origin, type) {
  this.name = name;
  this.origin = origin;
  this.type = type;

  //Some function that does something
  this.makeSound = function() {
    return "foo";
  }
}

function Mamal(name, origin, type, weight, height) {
  Animal.call(this, name, origin, type);
  this.weight = weight;
  this.height = height;

  this.makeSound = function() {
    return "I am a Mamal";
  }
}
```

So the question is how would I add a function to the Animal class AFTER 
it has been declared so that the Mamal class (or whatever subclass) also inherits it and can use it.

Comment: After what exactly has been declared?

Comment: Methods belong on the prototype, not the object itself. You can simply modify the prototype from the outside to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, what you actually want to achieve is that the `Mamal` class inherits methods from the `Animal` class? As in your question you have referred to them as Classes, I have provided an example with classes, rather than functions.

If so, you can declare Mamal like so:

```
class Mamal extends Animal {
    constructor(weight, height) {
        super();
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
    }

    // if you want to execute the Animal implementation of makeSound
    makeSound() {
        return super.makeSound();
    }

    // if you want to overwrite the Animal implementation of makeSound
    makeSound() {
        return "I am a mammal";
    }
}
```

> The extends keyword is used in class declarations or class expressions
>   to create a class as a child of another class.

[Sub classing with extends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Sub_classing_with_extends)
[Super class calls with super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Super_class_calls_with_super)

**Update**

Find the prototypal inheritance alternative here:

```
function Animal(name, origin, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.origin = origin;
    this.type = type;
}

Animal.prototype.makeSound = function () {
    return "foo";
};

function Mammal(weight, height) {
    this.weight = weight;
    this.height = height;
    Animal.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

Mammal.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype); //inherit the Animal object through the prototype chain

Mammal.prototype.makeSound = function () {
    return "I am a mammal";
}; //Overwrite the makeSound method inherited from Animal

const cheetah = new Animal('cheetah', 'Africa', 'mammal');
cheetah.makeSound();
//foo

const mammal = new Mammal('100kg', '1m');
mammal.makeSound();
//I am a mammal
```

Comment: `implements`? Is that a new keyword?

Comment: @zer00ne good catch, thanks for that. I was thinking in typescript where you can implement the class as an interface to define its structure. I've updated the answer to include only extends to better address the question.

Comment: Thank you for your help.I am interested in making the constructors in the format of functions as I have done above.The other way which you have done is obviously more efficient and perhaps intuitive but for reasons other than robustness I have to make the class in such way.

Comment: @TheHedge please find updated answer with the prototypal inheritance approach using functions and the prototype chain. FYI, classes in es6 are essentially just syntactical sugar built on the prototype chain.